# validation in android

Tags: android, passwords

how to insert username and password in database.how can we get that database as username and password

Comment: what can we do for validation

Answer (score 2):

I think Jeff has answered this question quite well in his post [You're Probably Storing Passwords Incorrectly](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/09/youre-probably-storing-passwords-incorrectly.html).

- Do not invent your own "clever" password storage scheme.
- Never store passwords as plaintext.
- Add a long, unique random salt to each password you store.
- Use a cryptographically secure hash.